# Shell arguments executed as commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

I'm using deployHQ to deploy my code to my servers. This product has this option to execute some commands after the deployment.

I'm not sure what they're doing on their side, but these commands that I've provided them are not executed in the manner that I'm intending and the output that I'm getting from them is similar to me executing commands like:

```
$> bash "ls"
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

or

```
$> bash "cd /usr/bin"
bash: cd /usr/bin: No such file or directory
```

Now my question is: Is there a way to tell bash (through some switch) to actually get it to execute the commands in the quoted arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `-c` is usually used to indicate commands that should be run by the invoked shell. Note that executing a non-mutating built-in such as `cd` this way is pointless.

Comment: I don't have access to what's outside the quotes :(

Comment: What's outside the quotes is vital for running commands like this. Invoke a separate script instead then.

Comment: ok i'm gonna delete it, the website had a bug and I was hoping to get some unix trickery help, but I worked around it. thanks